# About Countable union of Baire class 2 functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I Just wanted to say I do not know much about the Baire class 2 functions this why I am asking this question. For each $n\in\Bbb Z$, let $f_n\colon [n,n+1]\to\Bbb R$ be a function with Baire class 2 such that $f_{n}(n+1)=f_{n+1}(n+1)$. Now, define $f$ as follows $$f=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} f_n.$$ Clearly, $f$ is a function form $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R.$ Is $f$ still in Baire class $2$? Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: @bof,  it was a typo. I fixed

Comment: Think about "gluing" appropriate approximations of the $f_i$s together. In general, the result holds for all Baire classes, not just $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, a more general result holds:

> Suppose $f_i:[i,i+1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are Baire class $\alpha$ for $i\in\mathbb{N}$, with $f_i(i+1)=f_{i+1}(i+1)$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}f_i:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is also Baire class $\alpha$.

The proof is by induction. The base case $\alpha=0$ corresponds to gluing together continuous functions, so is trivial. Here's a sketch of how to handle the induction step (there are a couple issues with it which I mention below):

Let $(g^i_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}:[i,i+1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions approaching $f_i$ pointwise, each of which is Baire class $<\beta$. We want to "glue together" these approximations to get a sequence of approximations for the union of the $f_i$s. One natural idea here is to let $h_j=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}g_j^i$. There are a couple problems with this however:

- Although the $f_i$s "agree at the endpoints," the $g_j^i$s might not: we need not have $g_j^i(i+1)=g_j^{i+1}(i+1)$. That is, $h_j$ as defined above may not be a function.
- Even if each $g^i_j$ is simple their union need not be in case $\beta$ is a **limit** ordinal. For example, what if $\beta=\omega$ and $g^i_j$ is Baire class $i$? Then the $h_j$ defined above is Baire class $\omega$, which is too big.

Fixing these issues is a good exercise. The significant one is really the second bulletpoint, for which I'll give a hint:

> Redefine $h_j$ to only take into account the $g_j^i$s with $i\le j$. Basically, for $x>j+1$ we'll want $h_j(x)$ to be "boring." This won't affect the pointwise limit of the $h_j$s and will let us control their complexity.

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you for answer. Is there reason did not take $f_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ instead of $f_i$ , $i\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @00GB Nope, I just misread! Works fine with either.

Comment: Noah Schweber. If there is a reference for such fact that you may know. Thank you so much

Comment: @00GB No, I don't know of a reference for this.

Comment: Noah Schweber , I see thank you again

Comment: Noah Schweber, how about if each $f_i$ is a Borel function. what  can we say about $\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N} f_i$

Comment: The same basic idea works, just replace "approximation by functions" with "construction out of unions and intersections." Basically, the key point is that we're looking at "separated" unions: the various components aren't mixing in a complicated way. For example, show that if $X_i$ is a ${\bf \Pi^0_\alpha}$ subset of $[i,i+1]$ then $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}X_i$ is also ${\bf \Pi^0_\alpha}$.

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you. It is not clear now how this can be done but at least I know it is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124854/discussion-between-00gb-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: Noah Schweber,  To see $f=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Baire class $2.$ It is enough to show $f^{-1}(U)$  is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ for any open set $U$. But we have  $f^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} f_{i} ^{-1} (U)$, which is  $G_{\delta\sigma\sigma}=G_{\delta\sigma }$. So, $f$ is in Baire class $2$. Is that right

Comment: Noah Schweber, if $f\colon (a,b)\to\Bbb R$ is Baire class 2, define $F\colon [a,b]\to \Bbb R$ such that $F(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in(a,b)$ and $F(a)=F(b)=0$. What can we say about $F$? Is still in Baire class 2.

Comment: @00GB Yes, $F$ is still Baire class 2. Really this works for any Baire class $>0$ - first try proving that for Baire class 1.